# Word order with interchange

Tags: word-order

Which sentence is grammatically correct when A and B are some states:

“The A-B gap can be controlled or states can even be interchanged depending on temperature”

or

“The gap can be controlled or even interchanged A-state and B-state depending on temperature”

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you mean states as in solid-liquid, or something else? However the second sentence is wrong in any context.

Comment: The second sentence implies that the gap interchanged two things. I think that's not what you meant to write. Your first sentence is OK as far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you mean by interchanging states? Transitioning between states, or something else? Is this about state machines?

Comment: If the temperature dictates the gap and possible reversible transformation, 'depending on temperature' is incorrect. The sentences as they appear mean 'At certain temperatures, we are able to adjust the A-B gap and even effect interconversion' (though (2) is ungrammatical). Perhaps you intend 'By adjusting the temperature, it is possible to adjust the gap between A and B, and even to effect conversion from one state to the other.' I'm not sure what gap is being referred to ... the difference in the free energies of different states?